# Image resize in Java breaks on some JPGs

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jpeg

I'm using the code below to resize images and store them on the server. However, with some JPGs, the resize produces a reddish tint on the image. Any ideas what could be causing this? Here's the original image: http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/PNCWWD01.jpg and here's what it produces afterward: http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/PABDFC01__1289231445291.jpg

Photoshop CS5 on the Mac is used to produce the JPG input for this app. Thanks.

```
public BufferedImage resizeVeryHigh(InputStream inputStream, File resizedFile) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
  try {
      Image newImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
      int newWidth = (int)this.targetWidth;
      ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);
      Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
      Image resizedImage = null;

      int iWidth = image.getWidth(null);
      int iHeight = image.getHeight(null);

      // This code ensures that all the pixels in the image are loaded.
      Image temp = new ImageIcon(resizedImage).getImage();

      // Create the buffered image.
      bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(temp.getWidth(null), temp.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

      // Copy image to buffered image.
      Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

      // Clear background and paint the image.
      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, temp.getWidth(null), temp.getHeight(null));
      g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
      g.dispose();

      // Encodes image as a JPEG data stream
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resizedFile);
      JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
      JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bufferedImage);
      param.setQuality(1.0f, true);
      encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
      encoder.encode(bufferedImage);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
        this.error = e.getMessage();
  }
      return bufferedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original [image](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/PNCWWD01.jpg) appears to be a normal RGB image. As the image is opaque, I'm sure what `setColor()` and `fillRect()` add, but they are not the problem. The reddish cast suggests an incorrectly initialized ARGB buffer or an incorrectly chosen graphics composite mode. You might try one of the [`ImageIO.write()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) methods to see if your `JPEGImageEncoder` is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, the issue had to do with the [`progressive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) setting in the Save for Web & Devices in Photoshop. Once I toggled that on, the file was processed fine by the Java app. Why, I don't know. Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `progressive` in the JPEG specification. Possibly this is an artifact of the encoder's support for the feature.